# How can I write an IIF() function in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange

How can I write an IFF function in Informatica for the attached sample data. I have a target table which consist of different columns. I currently have different expressions like.
IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,1,1)))='',NULL,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,1,1))))

IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(DETAIL_INFO,2,4)))='',NULL,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(DETAIL_INFO,2,4))))

The first expression above picks up H from the first row below and assigns it to a column A, there is another expression function which assigns P to another column B, it continues until it reaches the last character on the first row and assigns it to a column P.
The second IFF function above reads 1 and assign it to a column W, then similar expression with different position assings P to a certain column X,another assins 009046678402 to column Y, then another assigns 40 to Z.
What i want to achieve is that, after reading and assigning values on the second row, if the next row after that starts with a 'D' again, it should still read it. But the current IFF function I have, only reads if there is rows alternate as
HP...
D1...
where as I want that if there is a scenario as shown in the attachment where you have
HP...
D1...
D2...
D3...
it should still read the and assign values of[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cac4I.png) D1..., D2..., D3...

HP2519263013900HWA8365C  DEFORD DONITA 1245327121 1184950479   2012516     0 201909202019092016       0
D1   P00904667840240

Comment: can you not use some kind of script like Python,C# to process the data first? It will make life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by creating variable ports for each field and replacing the null in my TRIM with their respective variable ports   like below                IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,1,1)))='',v_ID,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,1,1)))),
IIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,2,4)))='',v_LST_Name,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(HEADER_INFO,2,4))))